# How I can install some gcc compilers in arch linux?

Tags: arch-linux, make, gcc

I need to install earlier gcc than now. I already have gcc-10. I must install gcc-8 or gcc-6 in my computer then to build old project. I download the gcc-6 from github and tried install it as shown in this guide https://gist.github.com/slizzered/a9dc4e13cb1c7fffec53. I got the error: `target not found: libart-lgpl` . Google was show me than it's error occurs due to than this package is't contents from main repository. Stop! Ones again. If I want to build gcc-6 then I need to download and install `yaourt` then next install `libart-lgpl` which is not in the official repository? Pleas help my download & install some gcc compilers from my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify both gcc and gcc-libs. For example, if you want to downgrade from 7.1.1 to 6.3.1:

Method 1)

`pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/gcc-6.3.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz /var/cache/pacman/pkg/gcc-libs-6.3.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz`

Method 2)

`downgrade gcc gcc-libs`
And select wanted versions.

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475253/archlinux-downgrade-gcc-from-5-2-to-4-8